# I cannot find a barrel adjuster on my bike

Tags: maintenance, gears, cable

I tried to adjust the cable tension but there it litterally no way to adjust it on the front derailleur on a 22.5" GMC Denali 700cc Men's Bike

Generic photo from walmart.com
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a clear photo?    Use "edit" just below your question, to add one or two photos showing the shifter and the front derailler.  Could be there isn't a barrel adjuster for the front gears - My road bike doesn't have one.  I have added a generic photo from walmart.com

Answer (score 7):

You might not have one. Check near the place where the cable exists the front shifter or on the cable, but on a BSO like this, you most likely don't have one.

Your options are to install an [(inline) barrel adjuster](http://jagwire.com/products/small-parts/inline-adjusters?products/v/Inline_Adjusters) or just do the [adjustments](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustment) without the barrel adjuster (which just allows for fine tuning, really -- you can do all the adjustments without it, but they will be finickier).

Comment: Sorry answers don't show when doing reviews, so I missed this.   Is it possible there's some adjustment in the brifter?  Or is the trim feature priced above this bike?

Comment: They aren't built with brifters. They have regular MTB twist shifters installed  in the center of the bar (I'll let you work out how they do that).

Comment: How do you change gear on the drops or hoods?  That's LUDICROUS!    I'd say OP has to use the slightly-loose fixing bolt method to adjust the cable, or buy and install an inline adjuster.

Comment: @batman - I read somewhere a while back that there were a number of BSOs being made where the drops were welded to the bar after a grip shifter was installed. This could be one......

Comment: Criggie - The bike costs about as much as a pair of off brand shifters (e.g. Microshift). DWGKNZ - What I've heard is that the bar is cut in the center (where the stem clamps) to put on the shifters). In any case, I wouldn't trust the bar with that installation mechanism.

Comment: Twist grips! OMG. That's really putting "bicycle shaped" to the test. Talk about designed not to be maintained.

Comment: Yes. I see some of these at work. Not really the most trust inspiring.